# How to migrate resources registry resources to Plone 5

Tags: plone, genericsetup, plone-5.x

I have an add-on ([collective.lazysizes](https://github.com/collective/collective.lazysizes)) that includes a couple of JavaScript resources into Plone 4 resource registry using the following `jsregistry.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object name="portal_javascripts">
  <javascript id="++resource++collective.lazysizes/ls.respimg.min.js"
      cacheable="True" compression="none" cookable="True" enabled="True"
      expression="" inline="False" />
  <javascript id="++resource++collective.lazysizes/lazysizes.min.js"
      cacheable="True" compression="none" cookable="True" enabled="True"
      expression="" inline="False" />
</object>
```

How do I convert this into a Plone 5 bundle in `registry.xml`? Do I have to join the scripts into one file? How? Do I have to add a `resources` key into the bundle? What should it contain? What about more than one CSS resources?

I found the [documentation](http://docs.plone.org/adapt-and-extend/theming/resourceregistry.html#migrating-older-code-to-the-new-resource-registry) complex, sometimes contradictory and not pretty clear on this.

Comment: I note that [lazysizes.(min.)js](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/blob/gh-pages/lazysizes.js#L6) is already compatible with requirejs (if I read it correctly).   I'm not sure about the plugin though....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

- put all your JS in a single file (named lazysizes-bundle.js for instance). It can be done manually by copy/pasting them (we might also use npm and gulp, declare our JS dependencies in package.json and generate this bundle automatically, but in this very case, that's just 2 files, it might be overkill),
- declare this bundle in `registry.xml`:

`<records prefix="plone.bundles/lazysizes"
            interface='Products.CMFPlone.interfaces.IBundleRegistry'>
    <value key="enabled">True</value>
    <value key="jscompilation">++resource++collective.lazysizes/lazysizes-bundle.js</value>
    <value key="last_compilation">2016-01-01 00:00:00</value>
    <value key="compile">False</value>
    <value key="depends">plone</value>
  </records>`

We set `compile` to False so Plone will not try to generate this bundle, so our manually-generated bundle is preserved.

Notes:

- you are right, the doc is not clear right now, but this branch will be soon merged https://github.com/plone/documentation/commits/resource_registry_doc_improvements and it will be much better then.
- as you see, each add-on will bring its own bundle, BUT they can be merged into metabundles (see github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/issues/1277 that will be part of 5.0.3)

Comment: shouldn't it be added to the Plone bundle, rather than creating a new bundle?

Comment: Nice point @Danimal. Defining a new bundle for every add-on will lead Plone to have *a lot* of bundles?

Comment: @ebrehault the part of the documentation that confuses me more is the one stating [Plone will add all jsregistry.xml JavaScripts and cssregistry.xml CSS into a "plone-legacy" Resource Registry bundle](http://docs.plone.org/adapt-and-extend/theming/resourceregistry.html#old-registry-migration-and-compatibility); this should work, but is not.

Comment: @Danimal Plone default bundles are generated using a frontend tool chain (in the mockup package) and it is not easy (nor desirable) to integrate add-ons JS/CSS into those bundles.

Comment: @keul yes each add-on will bring its own bundle, BUT they can be merged into metabundles (see https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/issues/1277 that will be part of 5.0.3).

Comment: @ebrehault that's an important news! Please consider adding this also to you answer!